# How To Make It Work For Any No Of Rows And Cols

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array

Below is a code to display the `n*m` matrix where **n** & **m** are the number of *rows and columns* user want respectively

Ideally, It should work for any number of **n and m**, but my code only works for cases where *n=m* i.e **n*n** matrix

The Code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //define
    int i,j; // iterators - rows, cols
    int n,m; // number store

    //input + array declaration
    printf("Enter Number Of Rows You Want: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("\nEnter Number Of Cols You Want: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    // user input no of elelments in m and n
    int a[m][n];

    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("\nEnter Values For [%d][%d]: ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    // printing
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        if(j==n){
            printf("\n");
         }    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am taking the input using nested for loop in `&arr[n][m]` and printing it using the same concept but in a new loop

Which Returns:
[Executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df2UA.png)

So I want to know how I can adapt my code to work for any n*m matrix where **n is no of rows** and **m is no of columns**?

***I am using windows 10 and the editor is VS Code***

Any code blocks will be appreciated

Comment: Your loops are errorous, both of them are iterating over n, change second loops.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` -> `for(i=0; i<m; i++)`

Comment: Do you have rows/columns reversed? `int a[m][n];` --> `int a[n][m];` perhaps.

Comment: Does MS VC now support the variable length array `int a[m][n];` ?

Comment: I am new but yes it worked fine with me, it at least returns something and not errors:)

Comment: I fixed it now as stated by **kaylum** **Weather&  Vane**. as `int a[n][m]` & `for(j=0; j<m; j++)` and now the program works like a charm.

Comment: @Skeomer I haven't noticed this silly mistake, I will take care from next time, thanks

Comment: @WeatherVane, No. CL does not support VLA.

Comment: `j`,`k`,`m`,`n` ? giving longer descriptive names does help in avoiding this kind of confusions.

Comment: @ChefGladiator that is what I thought but the question indicates "VS Code". Presumably not VC compiler, since the program compiled.

Comment: WeatherVane, no worries.  @HarshShukla There is clang-cl (clang 11)packaged with V.Studio 2019.  We use clang-cl on Win10. And Visual Studio 2019 debugger, is priceless. Recommended.